# I installed tailwindcss. But live watch doesn't work properly

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

To check my output I have to run "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch" this command after calling every new tailwind class.

I tried many times and watched many tutorial but failed to run ☹️

Comment: did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

First Verify whether you have the input.css and output.css file in src and dist folder respectively.

dist

- output.css

src

- input.css

You can add following code in package.json file to automatically run watch command each time you add a new class and save.

```
{
  "scripts": {
  "watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
 }
}
```

In terminal :-
Run following Command

```
npm run watch
```